# Ant LineContains comma separated Value

Tags: ant

I have a property which contained a string and now want to change it to be a comma separated list to test lines in a file.

Currently with one value the following works:

```
<loadfile property="contents" srcFile="output.log">
    <filterchain>
        <linecontains>
            <contains value="${findvalue}"></contains>
        </linecontains>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

So if a line in a file contains:
Hello World!

And value of findvalue = 'World' it would find the line.  Now we want to find all lines that may match multiple words.  So if lines of a file contain:
Hello World!
Bye Everyone!

We want to set the property findvalue = World,Everyone and pickup both lines of the file.  Hopefully I am making sense on this, little hard for me to fully explain.  Any ideas on how to best accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a `linecontainsregexp` filter to get lines that match a certain regular expression. The trick is to convert the comma-separated list of values into a single regex.

If the property `findvalue` is `World,Everyone`, the regex could simply be `World|Everyone`, which means the line contains either `World` *or* `Everyone`.

```
<property name="findvalue" value="World,Everyone" />
<loadresource property="findvalueRegex">
    <propertyresource name="findvalue"/>
    <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
            <filetokenizer/>
            <replacestring from="," to="|" />
        </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
</loadresource>
```

Then pass the `findvalueRegex` property containing this regex to the `linecontainsregexp` filter:

```
<loadfile property="contents" srcFile="output.log">
    <filterchain>
        <linecontainsregexp>
            <regexp pattern="${findvalueRegex}" />
        </linecontainsregexp>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

linecontains takes multiple contains.

```
<loadfile property="contents" srcFile="output.log">
    <filterchain>
        <linecontains>
            <contains value="${findvalue1}"/>
            <contains value="${findvalue2}"/>
            .
            .
            .. and so on..
        </linecontains>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

This would be helpful only when you have a defined list of tokens to be searched and you don't want them to be fetched dynamically.
I know it's too late to answer but it might help someone else like me. :)